# Travel APIs how to integrate them all?

Tags: asp.net, api

I may start working on a project very similar to Hipmunk.com, where it pulls the hotel cost information by calling different APIs (like expedia, orbitz, travelocity, hotels.com etc)

I did some research on this, but I am not able to find any unique hotel id or any field to match the hotels between several API's. Anyone have experience on how can to compare the hotel from expedia with orbitz or travelcity etc?

Thanks

EDIT: Google also doing the same thing http://www.google.com/hotelfinder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen of GDS systems, and these API's there is rarely a unique identifier between systems for e.g. hotels

Airports, airlines and countries have unique ISO identifiers: http://www.iso-code.com/airports.2.html

I would guess you are going to have to have your own internal mapping to identify and disambiguate the properties.

:|

Answer (score 0):

When you get started with hotel APIs, the choice of free ones isn't really that big, see e.g. [here for an overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185961/travel-hotel-apis/15672534#15672534).

The most extensive and accessible one is Expedia's EAN http://developer.ean.com/ which includes Sabre and Venere with unique IDs but still each structured differently. 
That is, you are looking into different database tables.

You do get several identifies such as Name, Address, and coordinates, which can serve for unique identification, assuming they are free of errors. Which is an assumption.