# How to get TripAdvisor photos, as Apple Maps does

Tags: google-places-api, apple-maps, tripadvisor

Does anyone know if it is possible to access TripAdvisor photos in the same way that Apple Maps does: [image]

I've looked at the [TripAdvisor api docs](http://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/) but photo queries don't seem to be a feature. If that is true then how does Apple Maps do it?

I am currently using the Google Places API, but having quite a few issues with it, including image quality (not referring to resolution here, just the types of photo and professionalism)

Thanks

Comment: Look closer at the /map-attractions one, it seems to have a call in it that includes photos. (http://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/map-attractions/). EDIT: Also, see this post about alternatives if that doesn't work out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185961/travel-hotel-apis

Comment: That's great, I totally missed that. Cheers for the link too, very helpful. So far I've been looking at TripAdvisor, Yelp and Google APIs. I'd like to mark your answer but I can't as it is a comment.

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn't turn that down, check the answers for the same thing if you would like to mark it.

Comment: I've done that now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closer at the [/map-attractions](http://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/map-attractions/) one, it seems to have a call in it that includes photos.

EDIT: Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185961/travel-hotel-apis) about alternatives if that doesn't work out.

Comment: Is this still possible? /map-attractions is a dead link now.